# How to calculate a row value based on the previous row value in the same column

Tags: recursion, updates, teradata

I have the following data set:

```
     DATE   CODE    RANK    PARTITION
       ?    ABS        0           1
 12/04/2014 RET        1           1
 20/04/2014 RET        2           1
 01/05/2014 ABS        2           1
 13/05/2014 RET        2           1
 01/06/2015 ABS        2           1
 09/10/2015 RETk       2           1
         ?  ABS        0           2
 02/04/2015 RET        1           2
 03/04/2015 RET        2           2
 04/04/2015 ABS        2           2
 05/04/2015 STT        3           2
 06/04/2015 RETk       4           2
 07/04/2015 RETk       4           2
```

RANK is the column I want to calculate in my SQL given the columns DATE, CODE AND the previous value of the same column. It's initialized here to 0. 
The logic I want to implement is as follows:

```
 If RANK-1 (previous row) IS NULL AND CODE = ABS THEN RANK = 0
 If RANK-1 (previous row) IS NULL AND CODE <> ABS THEN RANK <- (RANK-1) + 1
 If RANK-1 = 0 or 1 AND CODE = RET THEN RANK <-  (RANK-1) + 1
 If RANK-1 = 2 AND CODE = STT THEN RANK <- (RANK-1) + 1
 If RANK-1 = 3 AND CODE = RETk THEN RANK <-  (RANK-1) + 1
 If CODE = ABS THEN RANK <- (RANK-1) (previous row)
 Else 0
```

The Teradata release I am using is R14. The calculation is done on a partition basis as shown in the example above. I have added some more constraints in the model to make it clearer. In this example, if the current code is RET, I do not increase the rank until the previous one is 0 or 1. Similarly, If my current code is RETk, I do not increase the rank until the previous one is equal to 3, otherwise, I do not change the rank. I repeat the same process in the following partition and so on ...

I cannot figure out how to update the current column value given the previous one... I tried many logic implementation with OLAP functions without success. 
Can anyone give me a hint?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: You've tried `rows between 1 and 1 preceding`? Add your query, so we can see what you've tried so far.

Comment: rows between 1 and 1 preceding doesn't solve the problem because the column name is unknown at this stage: even if I do something like this: min(RANK) over (partition by ID order by DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), RANK isn't recognised

Comment: I was thinking about using a temporary variable inside my SQL query where I store the value of the previous row so I can use it in the current row calculation...does it make sense? How can I update the user defined variable with the previous row value?

Comment: Can you add some more rows and explain in detail what result you want and why?

Comment: The rankcol is calculated based on two parameters: the current code and the previous rank: the rank of the current row cannot be increased unless the previous row is equal to 1 and the current code is equal to a specific code. It is much more like as state machine or a recursive model. I have added a few more columns below and explained a little bit more. Hope this is clearer

Comment: It's still not clear, based on your description you will never get a rank higher than 3? When do need to reset the rank to zero and when to increase (code RET or ABS)? And what's your Teradata release?

Comment: I apologize for my unclear explanation.. The Teradata release I am using is R14. The calculation is done on a partition basis as shown in the example above. I have added some more constraints in the model to make it clearer. In this example, if the current code is RET, I do not increase the rank until the previous one is 0 or 1. Similarly, If my current code is RETk, I do not increase the rank until the previous one is equal to 3, otherwise, I do not change the rank. I repeat the same process in the following partition and so on ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a recursive query for tasks like this. But performance will be bad unless the number of rows per group is low.

First you need a way to advance to the next row, as the next row's date can't be calculated based on the current row's date you must materialize the data and add a ROW_NUMBER:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(dt DATE, CODE VARCHAR(10), rnk INT, part INT);

INSERT INTO tab(            NULL,'ABS' ,0 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2014-04-12','RET' ,1 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2014-04-20','RET' ,2 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2014-05-01','ABS' ,2 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2014-05-13','RET' ,2 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2014-06-01','ABS' ,2 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2014-10-09','RETk',2 ,          1);
INSERT INTO tab(            NULL,'ABS' ,0 ,          2);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2015-04-02','RET' ,1 ,          2);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2015-04-03','RET' ,2 ,          2);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2015-04-04','ABS' ,2 ,          2);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2015-04-05','STT' ,3 ,          2);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2015-04-06','RETk',4 ,          2);
INSERT INTO tab(DATE'2015-04-07','RETk',4 ,          2);

CREATE VOLATILE TABLE vt AS
 (
   SELECT dt, code, part
     -- used to find the next row
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY part ORDER BY dt) AS rn
   FROM tab
 ) WITH DATA
PRIMARY INDEX(part, rn)
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;
```

And now it's just applying your logic using CASE row after row:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (dt, code, rnk, part, rn) AS
 (
   SELECT
      dt
     ,code
     ,CASE WHEN code = 'ABS' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
     ,part
     ,rn
   FROM vt
   WHERE rn = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
      vt.dt
     ,vt.code
     ,CASE
         WHEN cte.rnk IN (0,1) AND vt.CODE = 'RET'  THEN cte.rnk + 1
         WHEN cte.rnk = 2      AND vt.CODE = 'STT'  THEN cte.rnk + 1
         WHEN cte.rnk = 3      AND vt.CODE = 'RETk' THEN cte.rnk + 1
         WHEN                      vt.CODE = 'ABS'  THEN cte.rnk
         ELSE cte.rnk
      END
     ,vt.part
     ,vt.rn
   FROM vt JOIN cte
     ON vt.part =cte.part
    AND vt.rn   =cte.rn + 1  
 ) 
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY part, dt;
```

But I think your logic is not actually like this (based on the previous rows exact RANK value), you're just stuck in procedural thinking :-)

You might be able to do what you want using OLAP-functions only...

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
create table table1
(
  datecol date,
  code varchar(10),
  rankcol integer
);     
--insert into table1 select '2014/05/13', 'RETj', 0;

select 
  case 
  when s1.code='ABS' and s2.rankcol = 1 then 1
  when s1.code='RET' and s2.rankcol = 0 then 1
  when s1.code='RET' and s2.rankcol = 1 then 2
  else 0
  end RET_res,
  s1.*, s2.*
from
(select rankcol, code, row_number() OVER (order by datecol) var1 from table1) s1,
(select rankcol, code, row_number() OVER (order by datecol) var1 from table1) s2
where s1.var1=s2.var1-1
order by s1.var1  
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I do not get the idea: the rankcol column you are refering to is equal to zero and isn't updated at all. What I need is return the value of rankcol that was previouly calculated in the previous row and use it as an input to calculate the rankcol in the current row,